# Windows forms C# label backColor change issue

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to create a forms version of a 'Simon' game that a youtuber called AngelSix provided a walkthrough of.  The original code is a console app and i am trying to create a version that runs on windows forms in visual studio.  The aim of the game is for the user to repeat a series of displayed colours which i am using a label to display as backcolor changes.  The method i am employing is to populate a list with a series of enum values (Blue, Green, Red, Yellow), which are selected by a random number generator and.  This is all working fine and i can get the backColor to display any individual element of the list by calling the index of the list explicitly.  But i want the colours displayed to follow the list and change the backColor according to each iteration of a for-loop over the elements in the list (with a Thread.Sleep of 500ms) between each, which the user can then attempt to copy the sequence of by pressing buttons named 'Blue', 'Green' etc

However, when i run the for-loop, to display the sequence of colours in the list, it appears that each element of the list is not displayed as a backColor except the final colour in the list.  Is there a re-set required at each iteration, or is this simply something that cannot be done in this way?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please share some code and a clear description of the problem. See the following guidelines - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

If you want to traverse the "color list" to set the BackColor of the label, using "[Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=netframework-4.8)" is a better choice.
Here is the simple demo.

```
List<Color> color = new List<Color> { Color.Blue, Color.Green, Color.Red, Color.Yellow };

private System.Timers.Timer myTimer;
int index = 0;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(500);
    this.myTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(myTimer_Elapsed);
    this.myTimer.Enabled = true;
    this.myTimer.Start();
}

private void myTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    // Set backcolor
    label1.BackColor = color[index];
    index++;
    // Check the index if out of range
    if (index >= color.Count)
    {
        myTimer.Stop();
    }
}
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Thanks Kyle!  That was really helpful!

Comment: @SimonBurdett: It is a custom on StackOverflow to mark helpful answers by clicking on the green arrow left to the answer.